# How to run project based on Nodejs, when getting message like Unresponsive script?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

When run nodejs project, the message like Unresponsive script

I got one project on git-hub based on **angularjs-rickshaw**. It is based on nodejs, bower.
Project: [ngyewch/angular-rickshaw](https://github.com/ngyewch/angular-rickshaw/tree/gh-pages)
Demo of above project: [DEMO](http://ngyewch.github.io/angular-rickshaw/#/home)

I want to run above project on my local system. I successfully installed every thing (nodejs, npm, bower). But When I type `http://localhost:3000/` I get nothing, I am new in Nodejs, **please help me on this. What will be the correct url?**

```
[neelabh@localhost angular-rickshaw]$ node server.js 
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Server running at http://localhost:3000/
```

I am getting following type of message if I ran 1.http://localhost:3000/ or 2. http://localhost:3000/#/home
[image]

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

var fs =require('fs');      //for image upload file handling

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port =3000;
var host ='localhost';
var serverPath ='/';
var staticPath ='/';

//var staticFilePath = __dirname + serverPath;
 var path = require('path');
 var staticFilePath = path.join(__dirname, serverPath);
// remove trailing slash if present
if(staticFilePath.substr(-1) === '/'){
    staticFilePath = staticFilePath.substr(0, staticFilePath.length - 1);
}

app.configure(function(){
    // compress static content
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(serverPath, express.static(staticFilePath));        //serve static files

    app.use(express.bodyParser());      //for post content / files - not sure if this is actually necessary?
});

//catch all route to serve index.html (main frontend app)
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(staticFilePath + staticPath+ 'index.html');
});

 app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server running at http://' + host + ':' + port + '/');
 })
//app.listen(port);

//console.log('Server running at http://'+host+':'+port.toString()+'/');
```

Comment: Try `http://localhost:3000/#/home`

Comment: The project you're referring to is AngularJS.   Where is your Node.js code that you added?

Comment: @kyrylkov Thanks for reply, Node.js is installed system-wise, when I run  `node --version` I am getting v0.12.7, I think you were asking nodejs is installed or not, Please let me know if anything you were asking..

Comment: @remus I tried `http://localhost:3000/#/home` but I am getting the message like Unresponsive script.....

Comment: @kyrylkov  "Where is your Node.js code that you added?" I didn't get your question correctly.............

Comment: Where `server.js` file comes from?  It's not a part of `angularjs-rickshaw`.  So where did you get it and what's in it?

Comment: @kyrylkov, Thanks for pointing out. Updated the link, server.js is not available in master_branch in 'gh-pages'  https://github.com/ngyewch/angular-rickshaw/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83616/discussion-between-kyrylkov-and-neelabh-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/ngyewch/angular-rickshaw/blob/gh-pages/server.js, `console.log('Server running at http://'+host+':'+port.toString()+'/')` should be a callback to `listen` call.  Otherwise `console.log` always gets executed, even if the server doesn't start properly.

The correct way is:

```
 app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server running at http://' + host + ':' + port + '/');
 });
```

For `staticFilePath` and in other path-related parts you should use `path.join`:

```
 var path = require('path');
 var staticFilePath = path.join(__dirname, serverPath);
```

Ultimately it's best to move all static files to `public` directory and serve it with [express.static](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) middleware:

```
'use strict';

 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();

 var port = 3000;

 app.use(express.static('public'));

 app.listen(port, function () {
   console.log('Server running at http://' + host + ':' + port + '/');
 });
```

Comment: Should I modify server.js file according to your code..If Yes where to put path =require('path');

Comment: Yes.  `var path` should go before `path.join`.

Comment: Please see the updated question I added server.js as you told me to do It is still unresponsive .....

Comment: `console.log` executed in callback?  You don't need to remove trailing slash manually.   `res.sendfile` should also use `path.join`.   Even better leave all this verboseness out, put all static files to `public` folder and use `app.use(express.static('public'))` to serve all static files in `public` folder.

Comment: console.log is giving error like `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Comment: using shortest code with `app.use(express.static('public'))`?